# How to configure a Symfony workflow

Tags: php, symfony, workflow, symfony4

I work on Symfony 4.2 version
I made an Workflow Service, who has three places draft, reviewed and published

I add to conf/products/framework.yaml this lines of code. But i don't understand what is currentPlace in the code. I worked by this example https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/workflow.html

```
workflows:
        article_publishing:
            type: 'workflow'
            audit_trail:
                enabled: true
            marking_store:
                type: 'multiple_state'
                arguments:
                    - 'currentPlace'
            supports:
                - App\Entity\Article
            initial_marking: draft
            places:
                -draft
                -reviewed
                -published
            transitions:
                to_review:
                    from: draft
                    to:   reviewed
                publish:
                    from: reviewed
                    to:   published
```

But when I refresh the site I get this error

```
   Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZbUA.png)

Comment: Could you show more exception's stack trace?

Comment: @sensorario I add an screenshot of the error now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it so that I removed the quotes from type and removed the arguments and added approved_by_admin and now it works.

```
framework:
  workflows:
    article_publishing:
      type: workflow
      audit_trail: true
      marking_store:
        type: multiple_state
      supports:
        - App\Entity\Article
      places:
        - draft
        - for_review
        - approved_by_admin
        - published
      transitions:
        to_for_review:
          from: draft
          to:   for_review
        to_approved_by_admin:
          from: for_review
          to: approved_by_admin
        to_published:
          from: approved_by_admin
          to:   published
        to_draft:
          from: for_review
          to:   draft
```

And I add to Controller this code

```
/**
     * @Route("/apply-transition/{article}", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function applyTransition(WorkflowInterface $articleWorkflow, Request $request, Article $article, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $slug = $article->getCategory()->getSlug();
        try {
            $articleWorkflow->apply($article, $request->request->get('transition'));
            $this->repository->flush();
        } catch (ExceptionInterface $e) {
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        $url = $router->generate('app_category_view', ([
            'slug' => $slug,
        ]));
        return new RedirectResponse($url);

    }
    /**
     * @Route("/resetMarking/{article}", methods={"POST"})
     */

    public function resetMarking(Article $article, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $slug = $article->getCategory()->getSlug();
        $article->setMarking([]);
        $this->repository->flush();
        $url = $router->generate('app_category_view', ([
            'slug' => $slug,
        ]));
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }
```

And to Entity I add this

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $marking;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $transitionContexts;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `places` section of your YAML configuration is invalid.

It should look like this :

```
places:
    - draft
    - reviewed
    - published
```

*Notice the space between the minus symbol and the item name*